# Looking for neural network samples

Tags: neural-network

I am making a program to recognize musical notes recorded by a human voice , I'm using a neural network and I wonder if I can find good samples of musical notes with human voice for my network ..... I've found thousands of patterns for other instruments but none for human voice

Comment: Stack Overflow is probably not the best place to ask for human musical tones.

Answer (score 0):

You can try places like the UCI Machine Learning Repository, but it's unlikely they'll have exactly what you're looking for.

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

If you can find even a small number of samples of different voices at known notes, though, you can construct a much fuller library by using pitch-shifting software (similar to auto-tune software.)  I believe there are free- or shareware versions available.

(**UPDATE:** If you do create your own, you might consider donating it to the repository.  I've seen work on neural networks to classify both western and non-western music by key or other categories, so there is some interest in music recognition.)